how to use css variables inside javascript in rollup
I have a UI components repo setup with rollup where I want to use my css variables inside my javascript files. I have done this in another repo which was using webpack and it was quite easy:
import vars from '!css-variables-loader!./variables.css';
Is there any plugin like css-variables-loader for rollup that I can use?
